# Probability of a state "being found in another"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

I'm sorry if something gets lost in translation, as my professor wrote all questions in portuguese, but what does it mean to ask the probability of finding "state  $|\alpha \rangle$ in state $|\beta\rangle$"?. What does it mean and how do I actually calculate it?

Comment: But what is the physical significance of it? Is it the probability of finding the particle state $|\beta\rangle$ after measuring state $|\alpha\rangle$?

Comment: Assuming $|\beta\rangle, |\alpha\rangle$ are normalized, it (presumably) means that if you have a quantum system prepared in a state $|\beta\rangle$ and measure, for example, the observable $|\alpha\rangle\langle \alpha|$, then the probability to obtain the measurement value $1$ equals to $|\langle \alpha|\beta\rangle|^2$. The state after the measurement then is $|\alpha\rangle$. You can in fact measure any observable, as long as $|\alpha\rangle$ is a non-degenerate eigenvector of the corresponding hermitian operator.

Comment: ...the aforementioned probability is then the probability to measure the value $a$, where $A|\alpha\rangle = a|\alpha\rangle$ is the eigenvalue to the (non-degenerate) eigenvector $|\alpha\rangle$ of the hermitian operator $A$, corresponding to the observable you measure.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I think the question can be interpreted so: you measured $|\alpha\rangle$ and measure immediately that; what is the probability that you get $|\beta\rangle$

Comment: The comment from Jason Funderberker is a correct answer (but for friendliness it would need to be presented with a little less jargon).

Comment: @AndrewSteane Yes, you're right. I don't have much time at the moment, so I just wanted to give a brief comment. I think someone else can extend this to an understandable answer. Can someone explain the close vote? To me, this is no homework-like question; in fact, I find it rather conceptual. Moreover, these (IMHO not very clear) phrases are used quite often.

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to think less formally: what are we actually prepare and measure. For example, we prepared system in state with definite angular momentum $|\alpha\rangle$ and measure momentum. What is the probability that momentum is $\beta$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The question can be formulated as follows " we prepare a system in state $|\alpha\rangle$ and measure. What is the probability that we measure $|\beta\rangle$?. The answer is obvious: assuming states are normalized, it is square of the norm of overlap the states, $|\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle|^2$.

I think the question is artificially confusing because we don't specify what we prepare and measure.  The answer is different from trivial $\{0,1\}$ if we prepare and measure different observables ( in terms of Quantum Information Science, prepare and measure in different bases).